# Adjust layout images and size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to adjust the images and size depending the page size to doesn't go outside the grid, but I couldn't make it.

I tried add theses lines below in CSS but it bugged the others images

```css
img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
}
```

The content should adjust the size of the image, but it isn't working

[image]

The image going outside the grid:

[image: SS]

You can see the live preview [here](http://test.legendsot.com/)

Answer (score 1):

do the exact opposite you are doing

```css
img {
  width:800px; /* this is optional */
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

OP's comment:

> I already dropped it (the `width:800px)`, but it messed with the images at right sidebar.

Then create a class something like `img-resposive` and for that class apply `max-width: 100%`. And use that class in images you want/need to

Comment: It will start messy with the others image for example https://i.imgur.com/tP38gcC.png Also the grid in http://test.legendsot.com/?view=ranking still bugged.

Comment: @vankk drop the `width:800px` which I said was optional in my answer

Comment: I already dropped it, but it messed with the images at right sidebar.

Comment: @vankk then create a class like `img-resposive` and for that class apply `max-width: 100%`. and use that class in images you want to

Comment: I tried that but it didn't worked. You can check it in live, also the grid in the link that I said above do you have any idea why is like that?

Comment: your http://test.legendsot.com/?view=ranking is not an image its a `table` so its not up for this, and the solution(s) I gave you it will fix your **images** 100% sure

Comment: I used `.resposive {
  max-width: 100%;
}` and at home I added `<div class="img-resposive">` Didn't understood what I missunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Just give max-width for image to 100%

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest if you are trying responsive design, use `50em;` instead of `800px`

They are both equal (except when window is resized.)